# MSSQL: Why does findAll not working after I have update the entity - Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have `3` entities.

```
    @Data
    public class Data {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;
    
        private String OrderNumber;
        private String ValveName;
        private String SerialNumber;
        private String ValvePort;
        private String TestNumber;
        private String ValveType;
        
        @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Current current;

        @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Flow flow;
```

And these two childs looks like this:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Current{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private float s0;
    private float s1;
    private float s2;
    private float s3;
```

And this

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Flow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private float f0;
    private float f1;
    private float f2;
    private float f3;
```

**Expection:**

When I save a new `data`, I will both save these two childs at the same time. The `data` is an object

```
Data data = new Data();
Flow flow = new Flow();
Current current = new Current ();

// Do some logic and fill the values for flow and current object and also data object
// Also include current and flow into data object
data.setCurrent(current);   
data.setFlow(flow); 

// Save to the database
data_Repository.save(data);
```

Also, if I change the fields in the `data`, I will just update both `current` and `flow`.

**Problems:**

When I pick up an `data-object` and then change one parameter, then I save it.

Then this will not work.

```
@Repository
public interface Data_Repository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE LOWER(order_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :orderNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valveName,'%')) AND LOWER(serial_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :serialNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_port) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valvePort,'%')) AND LOWER(test_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :testNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_type) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valveType,'%')) ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT :maxLog ROWS ONLY", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Data> findByMultipleValues(@Param("orderNumber") String orderNumber, @Param("valveName") String valveName, @Param("serialNumber") String serialNumber, @Param("valvePort")  String valvePort, @Param("testNumber") String testNumber, @Param("valveType") String valveType, @Param("maxLog") Integer maxLog);
```

The problem is this part:

```
LOWER(order_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :orderNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valveName,'%')) AND LOWER(serial_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :serialNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_port) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valvePort,'%')) AND LOWER(test_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :testNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_type) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valveType,'%'))
```

In MySQL, it works perfect!

But in Microsoft SQL...it does not work! Why?

I can still receive these rows by using, but not the `repository-command` above after **I HAVE CHANGED** the entity row. Why?

```
data_Service.findAll();
```

I'm using Microsoft 2012 SQL Server.

Summerize:

This results that it can give me `data`, even if I have changed the and saved one data entity.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT :maxLog ROWS ONLY", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Data> findByMultipleValues(@Param("maxLog") Integer maxLog);
```

This will not give me anything after I have updated one entity. The entities who are not updated, are still there avaiable too see.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE LOWER(order_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :orderNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valveName,'%')) AND LOWER(serial_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :serialNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_port) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valvePort,'%')) AND LOWER(test_number) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :testNumber,'%')) AND LOWER(valve_type) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%', :valveType,'%')) ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT :maxLog ROWS ONLY", nativeQuery = true)
        List<Data> findByMultipleValues(@Param("orderNumber") String orderNumber, @Param("valveName") String valveName, @Param("serialNumber") String serialNumber, @Param("valvePort")  String valvePort, @Param("testNumber") String testNumber, @Param("valveType") String valveType, @Param("maxLog") Integer maxLog);
```

Comment: Your question is little confusing, what is not working here? parameters or `findAll` function?

Comment: @code_mechanic `findAll` works perfect, but after I have updated one entity, it will disaperar when I try to search it with `findByMultipleValues` function.

Comment: The `Data` class you posted is a simple POJO class or entity? Because I am not seeing any `@Entity` annotation on this

Comment: @code_mechanic Oh sorry. They are all `@Entity` and they have their own `@repository` as well.

Comment: So your query which you said is a problem, working fine, its just that the result is not coming?

Comment: @code_mechanic Yes, the result that I have changed, are not coming if I'm using `findByMultipleValues`. But the results I have not changed, works with `findByMultipleValues`. That's weird.

Comment: Yes its weird if query happens in different transaction after the save transaction, so if you are querying in same transaction as save transaction, you would not see the result because the save is not committed, is that the issue?

Comment: @code_mechanic My theory. It seems that when I save `serialNumber` it saves as `NULL` in the database. Should not be like that....hmmm...

Comment: Yes and you also have serial number as param, so issue with the save it seems

Comment: @code_mechanic Yes! I'm using Vaadin CRUD AddOn for writing to the database, but it seems that my Hibernate Validation don't warn be about "this field cannot be null" when I try to save it.

Comment: Hibernate will only throw error if you use the validation annotations, although if it is a non-null field then you must have constraint in table as well.

Comment: @code_mechanic I found it out here. I had problems with this before and I have Spring Boot Validation in my pom.xml file. Still I get no warnings if I trying to save with NULL. https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/introduction-to-java-bean-validation

Comment: I meant that you need to use the validation annotations like `@NotNull` in this case over the field, which is missing in example you posted, have you used it and it still didn't work?

Comment: @code_mechanic Yes. I have included now `@NotNull` and I'm using Spring Validation. In this case, Vaadin Crud Add-On should stop the user for putting in Null values into the database. But for me, I get only errors when I putting in null in the database.

Comment: Thats what the annotation will prevent `null` value right, why it would prevent non-null value? or I didn't get your last comment

Comment: @code_mechanic This is how it should look like. Try to add an empty row. You are going to se "must not be null"-warning. https://alejandro.app.fi/crud-ui-demo/lazy-loading

Comment: By the way! I recommend Vaadin :)

Comment: I was referring to the errors on database operations not on UI, anyways if you have question regarding validation, you should post new question.

Comment: @code_mechanic Ok. Thank you. I will think about that.